# some phenomenon of mysql query in where condition compare char filed with int 0

Tags: mysql, char

Have a table ,

```
root@localhost:[test]05:35:05>desc t;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| studio_id | char(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

have two rows:

```
root@localhost:[test]05:35:29>select * from t;
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | studio_id                        |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | foo1                             |
|  2 | 299a0be4a5a79e6a59fdd251b19d78bb |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

found some strange query phenomenon, e.g.

```
# I can understand this
root@localhost:[test]05:37:00>select * from t where studio_id = '0';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
# I also understand this
root@localhost:[test]05:41:45>select * from t where studio_id = 1;
Empty set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)


# but I can't understand this
root@localhost:[test]05:36:21>select * from t where studio_id = 0;
+----+-----------+
| id | studio_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | foo1      |
+----+-----------+
```

why could have record returned, and why only `foo1` returned , what about `299a0be4a5a79e6a59fdd251b19d78bb`?

```
root@localhost:[test]05:38:20>select * from t where studio_id <> 0;
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | studio_id                        |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  2 | 299a0be4a5a79e6a59fdd251b19d78bb |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Strange indeed, it returns id 2 when `foo1` is has id 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f8a7/1

Comment: Here's a clue... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f8a7/5

Comment: @11mb and Strawberry Thanks! let me know could run sql online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is how mysql silently converts text to numbers to evaluate the number=text expression as described in mysql's documentation on [type conversion in expression evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html).

Number=text comparison expressions are evaluated by converting both operands to floating point numbers.

Text is converted to a number by evaluating the characters from left to right. As long as the characters can be evaluated as a valid number (sign, numbers, decimal point, etc), mysql considers it as a number. The conversion stops in the moment mysql encounters a character that cannot be used in a number (such as a letter), or would result in an ivalid number (such as a 2nd sign).

Text `'foo1'` is converted to 0 because its leftmost character is a letter.

Text `'299a0be4a5a79e6a59fdd251b19d78bb'` is converted to 299 because it starts with the characters 299 and then comes the letter `a` that cannot be interpreted as a number.

Comment: yeah, you are right. root@localhost:[test]06:59:07>select * from t where studio_id = 299.00;
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | studio_id                        |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  2 | 299a0be4a5a79e6a59fdd251b19d78bb |
+----+----------------------------------+

Comment: but I can't understand you said " or would result in an ivalid number (such as a 2nd sign)." . What's the mean?

Comment: Try `Select '-123-1'+0` and you will understand.