# Varchar seems casted to integer somehow in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I have the following column definition:

```
col varchar(8) not null
```

It contains ONLY `h` and `w` values:

```
col
h
h
w
w
w
h
```

The problem is that doing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.col = 0 limit 100;
```

Gives me some results, while it shouldn't.  It's integer, not varchar. What's happening? Also, what happens if I insert `0` as integer to such column?

EDIT:

It's NDB cluster table. Full table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `graph` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `neighbor` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`neighbor`,`type`)
) ENGINE=ndbcluster DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sample data:

```
id | neighbor | type
1    1          h
2    1          h
3    2          w
```

Sample SQL:

```
select * from graph g where g.type = 0;
```

Sample output:

```
id | neighbor | type
1    1          h
2    1          h
3    2          w
```

While `select * from graph g where g.type = 1;` returns an empty set.

Comment: you could at least post the results that you got (which are not supposed to be there)

Comment: SELECT * FROM t WHERE t.col = '0' limit 100; compare varchar values always with quotes.

Comment: I think this is the same behaviour http://stackoverflow.com/a/34990112/1354222